# How to rename dialog box buttons or create new in Ax 2012?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, dialog

Is it possible to rename dialog box buttons?
For example on `"okCancel"` can I rename the `"ok"` button as `"continue"`?

If not please guide me how can I create my own dialog box?

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A button has a "Text" property. 
You can set that property or do so by code:

```
okButton.text("Continue");
```

The `Box::okCancel` uses the `DialogBox` class which is a kernel class and cannot be changed. 
The `yesNoAxaptaForm` method on the other hand uses an AX form, so you can roll on your own. 
That said it seems to gain little value.

Also consider using the RunBase framework with a form, as demonstrated in the `Tutorial_RunbaseForm` class.

Comment: I mean the Box::okCancel
Where can I find that form which appears when we use Box::okCancel?
I saw the okCancel method in Class/Box, I created new method there, copied the okCancel code, but I did not understand what to change.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new method in class Dialog overwriting the control #okButton and call this method in your new dialog.
When Dialog class is create in the method new call the method initButtons, which can be overridden.

For example:

```
FormBuildButtonGroupControl     buttonGroup;
formBuildCommandButtonControl   okButton;
;
buttonGroup = dialogForm.buildDesign().control(#bottomGroup);
if (buttonGroup)
{
    okButton = dialogForm.buildDesign().control(#okButton);
    okButton.text("test");
}
```